# Firebase functions not recognizing express app routes outside of index.ts

Tags: typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I recently deployed a TypeScript project to firebase-functions with everything in index.ts. Everything worked but when I started to refactor my code I soon realized firebase does not recognize routes specified in files outside of index.ts (or the file where you wrap your express app in `functions.https.onRequest()`).

I have replicated the issue below:

```
//index.ts    
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'; 
import * as express from "express";

export const expressApp = express();

expressApp.get("/hi", (req, res)=> {
   res.send("hi");
})

export const TestApp = functions.https.onRequest(expressApp);
```

External file in same directory that adds the `"/hello"` route.

```
//external.ts
import { expressApp } from "./index";

expressApp.get("/hello", (req, res)=> {
    res.send("hello")
})
```

After I use `firebase-deploy`, the `"/hi"` route in index.ts works but the `"/hello"` route in external.ts does not (`Cannot GET /hello`).

My guess is that the TestApp is being exported to firebase-functions before it's called by any external files.

Is there any way to get around this in a TypeScript project?

Comment: could you show the firebase.json file aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start your project, the code inside `index.ts` is executed, but as it doesn't reference `external.ts` at all, that code is never executed.

What you can do instead is call `external.ts` from inside `index.ts` and then invoke it by passing in the `express` app you would like to modify.

```
//index.ts    
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'; 
import * as express from "express";
import {attachRoutes: attachExternalRoutes} from "./external";

export const expressApp = express();

expressApp.get("/hi", (req, res)=> {
   res.send("hi");
})

attachExternalRoutes(expressApp); // attaches routes in external

export const TestApp = functions.https.onRequest(expressApp);
```

```
//external.ts
export function attachRoutes(expressApp) {
  expressApp.get("/hello", (req, res)=> {
    res.send("hello")
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes! This makes perfect sense. Just tested it an it works. Thank you :)